# Mocking a Directive in another Module in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, videogular

I am using videogular and have created a directive that requires the videogular directive.

This all works fine, but not I want to unit test my directive.

I would like to mock the videogular directive so that I can manipulate the data returns via the API.

However my directive always picks up the concrete implementation of videogular.

I am trying to mock the videogular module implementation of the directive below with no luck. I then mock my own module as I normally would for unit tests.

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('com.2fdevs.videogular'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('com.2fdevs.videogular'),function($provide,$controllerProvider){
    videogular = function(){
        return {
            template: '<video class="test"></video>',
            transclude: true
        }
    };
    $controllerProvider.register('vgController', function(_$scope_){
        $scope = _$scope_;
        $scope.totalTime = 100;
    });
    $provide.factory('videogularDirective', videogular);
});
```

I've tried to inject it in the same way also into my own module with the same result.

How can I get it to use my mock not the concrete implementation ?

I now have

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('com.2fdevs.videogular'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('com.2fdevs.videogular'),function($provide,$controllerProvider,$compileProvider){
    videogular = function(){
        return {
            template: '<video class="test"></video>',
            transclude: true
        }
    };
    $provide.factory('videogularDirective', videogular);
    $compileProvider.directive('videogularDirective', videogular);
});
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('irisApp'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('irisApp', function ($provide) {

    $provide.constant('LoggingService', require('../../../server/mocks/LoggingService.mock'));
    $provide.constant('run', {});

}));
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $compile = _$compile_;
}));
```

But it still uses the concrete directive.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* override the directive, but you have to use the [`$compileProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider) for that, i.e.:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('com.2fdevs.videogular'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('com.2fdevs.videogular'),function($compileProvider, $controllerProvider){
    // ...
    // same as above
    $compileProvider.directive('videogularDirective', videogular);
});
```

Comment: I've tried this approach, see my code now above, I still get the concrete implementation. I must be doing something silly ?

Comment: Can you make sure that the real `videogularDirective` code is *NOT* loaded?